# Display floating points in f3 format in RDLC TABLIX

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc

In my report, I have a tablix. Now I want to show the numeric data in f3 format. I have set text box property of the tablix column to number and with three decimal points.

Now when the data is e.g. 12.120 then it shows me 12.12 instead of 12.120.

And I want to show when the data is like 12 to 12.000.

How to do it?

Comment: You should probably setup it as custom formatting in text box properties of your report and set format to 0.000

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 12.20;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.000", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, here's your [reference material](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use those format strings, or the placeholder style.

Examples:

```
Double value = 12.20D;

String str1 = String.Format("{0:F3}", value);
String str2 = value.ToString("F3");
String str3 = value.ToString("0.000");
```

To make this work with your `TextBox`, however, you will need to pass the entered values through a routine that applies said formatting.

Using the TextBox's `Validated` method is a good choice because it is fired after editing is complete, and not *while* the user is still typing (like `TextChanged` would):

```
private void textBox1_Validated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double dbl;
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) && 
        Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dbl))
    {
        //Replace with your formatting of choice...
        textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:F3}", dbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it why everybody is answering for the text box while I am talking about tablix in RDLC REPORT. See the tags.

Comment: The point is the same regardless.  Does your report item not have a format property?  Can you not put a proper format string in that property?

Comment: Yes I set the property to number and decimal points to 3. But not displaying desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [`TextBox.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to `f3`.